# How to wait for a function execution in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following function:

```
isUserUsed: function(username) {
  var result = true;
  User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(user){
      result = false;
    }
 });
  return result;
},
```

The called function `User.getUserByUsername()` is supposed to change the value for `result`. However, the main function `isUserUsed` returns before `User.getUserByUsername()` finishes. How can I control the flow of the code to wait for `User.getUserByUsername()` to finish before proceeding?

Thanks!

Comment: Promises. Checkout Bluebird (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: `if(err) throw err;` inside an async callback is one of the worst design patterns in node.js.  Don't do it - ever.

Answer (score 0):

maybe promise is your choise, click the link [[promise]](https://www.promisejs.org/) for detail;
after used promise, your code would like:

```js
isUserUsed: function(username) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var result = true;
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
      if(err) reject(err);
      if(user){
        resolve(false);
      }
   });
  });
  
},
```